# Datalist tag not working with django

Tags: django

I have written the code below to search within a drop down function. But after I put the django elements inside the datalist tag, the django objects are not seen anymore in the drop down.

```
<div style="display:table-cell;" id="search" >

    <label for="default">gs</label>
    <input type="text" id="default" list="src" placeholder="Type to search for GST">
    <datalist id="src">
    {% for list in opt_list %}
    <option value="{{list.name}}" size="5" ></option>
    {% endfor %}

    </datalist>    
    </div>
```

Comment: its a list that I'm sending from views.py file and on the template I'm looping it.

Comment: Well the cause of your issue is that is empty, so there isn't anything to loop over.

Comment: Hi @s_user !! Did you get the solution for it?